# Spring Cloud Contract Consumer side Cannot bind to DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

I have a spring cloud contract consumer that has the following error. I don't understand why my test case cannot bind to EmbeddedKafka.

Repo: https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/spring-cloud-contract-poc/

When I run https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/spring-cloud-contract-poc/blob/main/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/consumer/ConsumerApplicationTests.java

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contractVerifierKafkaMessageExchange' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/messaging/kafka/ContractVerifierKafkaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier]: Factory method 'contractVerifierKafkaMessageExchange' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier]: Factory method 'contractVerifierKafkaMessageExchange' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1089)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:852)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:165)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:147)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.ContractVerifierKafkaStubMessagesInitializer.prepareListener(ContractVerifierKafkaStubMessagesInitializer.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.ContractVerifierKafkaStubMessagesInitializer.initialize(ContractVerifierKafkaStubMessagesInitializer.java:40)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.KafkaStubMessages.<init>(KafkaStubMessages.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.ContractVerifierKafkaConfiguration.contractVerifierKafkaMessageExchange(ContractVerifierKafkaConfiguration.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 115 more
```

Consumer has the following `application-test.yml`.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:
      - ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'

    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'

    implementation 'org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-spring:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-jackson:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner"
    testImplementation "org.awaitility:awaitility:3.1.6"

    testImplementation project(":order-service")
}
```

I have the following test case in consumer

```java
package com.example.consumer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubFinder;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerPort;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.example.consumer.domain.Transactions;
import com.example.consumer.repository.TransactionRepository;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
  ids = {
    "com.example:order-service"
  },
  stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL
)
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {"transactions"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ConsumerApplicationTests {
  @Autowired
  ConsumerApplication consumerApplication;

  @Autowired
  private StubFinder stubFinder;

  @StubRunnerPort("order-service")
  private int port;

  @MockBean
  TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

  @Captor
  ArgumentCaptor<Transactions> transactionsArgumentCaptor;

  @Test
  public void shouldCreateTransaction() {
//    Mockito
//      .when(transactionRepository.save(Mockito.any(Transactions.class)))
//        .thenReturn(new Transactions());

//    Mockito.when(transactionRepository)
    stubFinder.trigger("CreateTransactionEvent");


  }
 
}
```

On the producer side, I have the following contract and baseclass

```
package contracts

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

def json = JsonOutput.toJson([
        [
                id         : "6b8bdc7d-a91a-4e3f-a299-cb621590f337",
                amount     : "CHF 1000",
                iban       : "CH93-0000-0000-0000-0000-0",
                date       : "01-22-2022",
                description: "Online payment CHF"
        ]
])

Contract.make {
    description "Create Transaction Event"
    label 'CreateTransactionEvent'

    input {
        triggeredBy('sendMessage()')
    }

    outputMessage {
        sentTo("transactions")
        body(json)
    }
}
```

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.boot.AutoConfigureMessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.example.Application;
import com.example.domain.Transactions;
import com.example.dto.TransactionDto;
import com.example.mq.send.SendMessage;
import com.example.repository.TransactionRepository;
import com.example.service.TransactionService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;

@SpringBootTest(
  classes = {Application.class},
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = {"transactions"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
//@Import(value = {JacksonConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BaseClass {

  public static final UUID transactionId = UUID.fromString("5EF60C78-2D38-4936-A736-235E0A6B2177");

  public static final TransactionDto transactionDto = new TransactionDto();

  static {
    transactionDto.setId(transactionId);
    transactionDto.setAmount("CHF 1000");
    transactionDto.setIban("CH93-0000-0000-0000-0000-0");
    transactionDto.setDate(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 22));
    transactionDto.setDescription("Online payment CHF");
  }

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Autowired
  private ModelMapper modelMapper;

//  @Autowired
//  private WebApplicationContext context;

  @Autowired
  private TransactionsController transactionsController;

  @MockBean
  private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

  @MockBean
  private SendMessage sendMessage;

  @Autowired
  private TransactionService transactionService;

//  @MockBean
//  private TransactionService transactionService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    Transactions transactions = modelMapper.map(transactionDto, Transactions.class);

    List<Transactions> expected = Arrays.asList(transactions);
    Page transactionsPage = new PageImpl<>(expected);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(sendMessage).send(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Object.class));
    Mockito.when(transactionRepository.findAll(ArgumentMatchers.any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(transactionsPage);
    Mockito.when(transactionRepository.findById(transactionId)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(transactions));
    Mockito.when(transactionRepository.save(transactions)).thenReturn(transactions);

//    Mockito.when(transactionService.postTransaction(transactionDto)).thenReturn(transactionId);

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(transactionsController);
  }

  public void sendMessage() {
    transactionService.postTransaction(transactionDto);
  }
}
```

I have no idea why consumer cannot load the applicationcontext and the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory, given I have provided the required properties. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1089)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:852)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:165)
...
```

This means that the map of consumer properties being used to create the factory contains an entry with a `null` key or value, which is not allowed.

Use a debugger in the factory constructor to examine the `configs` map, to see which property is the culprit.

Comment: I had to comment out the aot plugin because I got an error about `@MockBean` not being supported by it. I got it to build but it has too many dependencies (e.g. postgresql). If you can provide a stripped-down version with minimal deps that exhibits the behavior I can help debug it; but I am not going to install postgresql.

Comment: Hi @gary. Thanks for your response. You can use the `docker-compose up -d` to start a postgres docker container. The docker-compose file is located at the project root. 

I am debugging the project too and it seems the producer side of the project is having some issue too. When I `./gradlew :order-service:contractTest`, all the contract test failed....

Comment: Hi @Gary. I am now facing a dilemma. If I add 

```java
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = {Application.class},
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
)
```

to the `BaseClass` in producer side, the test would throw the `springSecurityFilterChain` error.

`delegate cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: delegate cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.`